# Adobe Edge/JQuery: animation doesn't work

Tags: jquery, animation, adobe-edge

For a college assignment I have to develop a product site for Smegg fridges in Adobe Edge Animate. My problem is I want the logo to have a constant opacity transition between full opacity and something like let's say 30%, and then back to 100%, this looping the whole time. I wrote some jQuery code but it doesn't work. Sorry for my bad English it's not my native language. Here is the code:

```
//Edge symbol: 'stage'
(function(symbolName) {


  Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "document", "compositionReady", function(sym, e) {
     // insert code to be run when the composition is fully loaded here

     var timer = $.timer(logoHandler, 1000);

        function logoHandler() { 
            var state = true;

        if ( state ) {
            $( "#smegLogo" ).animate({
                opacity: 0.3
            }, 500 );
        } else {
            $( "#smegLogo" ).animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, 500 );
        }
        state = !state;

        };

     timer.play();

  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

http://jsbin.com/abecoz/1/edit

```
var c=0;
var op = [ '0.3' , '1' ];
function loopLogo(){  
  $("#smegLogo").animate({opacity: op[c++%2]},400, loopLogo); // <- ani. callback
}

loopLogo(); // start loop
```

Comment: Yes, first of all thank you for taking the time to help me. Problem is when I paste your code in my project it doesn't work either. Could the problem be that #smegLogo is converted to symbol in Adobe Edge?

Comment: Well, I finally found the problem. For a unknow reason I can't use '#' in Adobe Edge. So $("#smegLogo") has to be $("smegLogo"). Thanks for your code anyway, I will use yours.

Comment: @SylvainVansteelandt interesting how adobe takes care of that tags.... strange. Well glad for you you did it ! thanks! happy coding

Comment: The reason is that the selector is only interested in finding things by ID. The $ is a function of the symbol, NOT JQuery.